# set sequence value in options

Tags: php, sqlsrv

How can I set the value of `<option>` with sequence number `1 2 3` depending on number of `$row['table_name']`

```
$sql = "SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
//$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);                  
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
 echo "<option value=".$row['table_name'].">".$row['table_name']."</option>";
}
```

Thank you..

Comment: `sql = "SELECT id,table_name from information_schema.tables";` and then use that `id` in option value section.  BTW I am unable to understand the sentence-> `depending on number of $row['table_name']`=>what this exactly mean?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Assume I have 3 tables in database, if I apply this into HTML it is like `<option value='1'>Table 1</option><option value='2'>Table 2</option><option value='3'>Table 3</option>`

Comment: What is your problem then?I am unable to understand.

Comment: I want change `value=."$row['table_name'].">"` to sequence of number..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have a counter variable, say `$i` which would be printed in `value` attribute of your `option` tag, and then incremented for next loop iteration.

`$i=1;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    echo "<option value=".$i++.">".$row['table_name']."</option>";
}`

Comment: My Pleasure, @kin!

Comment: @kin  May be it's ok, but i will prefer to use table id column so that in future you can use that id to reference your data correctly in row.

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank you for your advice. I tried your method before but not work for me.

Comment: @kin  i know . but suppose a scenario that  your table have 4 records:- `1 table1, 2 table2, 3 table3 ,4 table4`. Now you deleted 3rd record from db. So when you are using this code and trying to send option value to do some updation then you will got problem because option that have `table4` will have value `3` which actually doen't exist in db at all. so you will face error. I told it for future purpose

Comment: @AlivetoDie true, you are right. Thank You for remind me :)

Comment: @kim so do you want me to post it as a solution? also if you want to show record in table then it's ok(sequential order), but for select-box option value,it's desauster(never do sequentail order). So let me know if you want me to post it as an answer. What you can do is use `asc` in query to get sequential order like 1,2,4,5,6... (suppose 3rd record is deleted)

Comment: @kin, by the way you may vote up my answer if it helped you! 